# How to be sure, that web application (html/js) is open in Task Module?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created [a message extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions) app for MS TEAMS. I use [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules). And a single page application was created especially for this message extensions. It works. I just **do NOT** want that single page application can be opened in a browser. It should work only inside the Task Module. Is any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Teams client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/using-teams-client-sdk), especially `microsoftTeams.getContext`. You could do something like have your content hidden, or empty, and then only call your API/show your content/whatever, when the getContext returns.